# Add list of stars in room to a sidebar

Tags: feature-request, chat, mobile-web

The new mobile chat interface is nice, and much more functional than the old version.  Because of the issues with the old interface, I frequently used [Chatsey](https://stackapps.com/questions/4659/chatsey-an-android-app-for-se-chat) when all I had was my phone.  One feature from Chatsey that I'd like to see in the new web version is the room info sidebar.  That sidebar includes the room description and standard chat links, but more importantly it also includes a list of current users in the room and the top three stars for the room.  This is information that I'd like to have easy access to from the mobile web interface.  I see that there is a drop down menu for current users, but there is no such thing for stars.

(Yes, I know I can open the menu and click through to the full list of stars, but this 1. takes me away from chat, and 2. is generally overkill since I only want the current top stars.)

Answer (score 5):

[image]

The message layout can be improved to match that used for messages generally, I've just pasted in a screenshot of the desktop stars here.

Comment: This would be perfect!

Comment: That's a good idea. Will think about this more :) Thanks